# Appending a new textbox onclick of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to write a simplest code, like onclick of button a new textbox with unique id should be assigned and appended to the existing ones.

```
function appendRow()
{
var x = 1;
for(var i=0; i < x; i++)
{
    var d = document.getElementById('div');
    d.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='tst"+ x +"'><br >";
}
++x;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div">
 <button onclick ="appendRow()" value="Add Row">Add Row</button>
 </div>
```

This might be very simple for techies.

Thanks.

Comment: Aside from your code replacing the button instead of appending, what doesn't work in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are replacing the button. You have to append the new div to the already created elements. Try to use `+=` instead of `=`.

Also there is not need for a loop. You can assign unique id with just an inceasing var

Try:

```
var x=1
function appendRow()
{
   var d = document.getElementById('div');
   d.innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='tst"+ x++ +"'><br >";
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gLfsxz26/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems extremely simple :)

Comment: @laasosto Have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLfsxz26/1/) with an issue facing, can you pls lookinto and fix it. On adding new textbox the values entered in previous gets deleted automatically.

Comment: @Basky You have to use jQuery for that, Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/gLfsxz26/2/